# mpdf will not open image with allow_url_fopen set to On

Tags: php, mpdf

With the PHP library [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) I get the error

> could not find image file

when looking for jpgs within the html.

This doesnt happen when allow_url_fopen is set to Off, however I need that setting to be on.

Comment: its try to download image with http:// , you can remove img src tag (http links) with str_replace , strtr  ,but  do you read the manual maybe there is an option for skip downloading images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change a check within mpdf.php where it checks if allow_url_fopen is Off, if it is it does not use cURL. I changed the code from

```
if ((!$data || !$type) && !ini_get('allow_url_fopen') && function_exists("curl_init")) {
    $this->file_get_contents_by_curl($file, $data);     // needs full url?? even on local (never needed for local)
    if ($data) { $type = $this->_imageTypeFromString($data); }
}
```

to

```
if ((!$data || !$type) && ini_get('allow_url_fopen') && function_exists("curl_init")) {
    $this->file_get_contents_by_curl($file, $data);     // needs full url?? even on local (never needed for local)
    if ($data) { $type = $this->_imageTypeFromString($data); }
}
```